# How to attach remove icon with dynamically added images programmatically in android?

Tags: android, imageview

I am adding ImageView dynamically inside a RelativeLayout programmatically but I also need to attach remove icon/button with onClick handler with those dynamic ImageViews. So that if I click on any of the delete icon related to that dynamic image view will be deleted.

Here is my code where I am adding dynamic image views inside the layout:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setId(id);
        iv.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), (int)iconTable[id]));
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        iv.setLayoutParams(lp);

        rl.addView(iv);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? Its a bit unclear.

Comment: Hi Shaishav, actually I am adding emoji on image dynamically but I also need to add delete option with that emoji. User can add more emoji and if they don't need they also can delete.

Comment: And also each emoji can move around the image so if emoji move then attached delete icon also should be moved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to create a custom component. Something like this:

```
public class DeletableImageView extends LinearLayout {

    private ImageView mImage;
    private Button mButton;

    DeletableImageListener mListener

    public DeletableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public DeletableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public DeletableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        inflate(context, R.layout.deletable_image, this);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        mImage= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        mButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.deleteMe(DeletableImageView.this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setListener(DeleteableImageListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface DeletableImageListener {
        void deleteMe(DeletableImageView me);
    }

   public void setImage(Drawable drawable) {
       mImage.setBackground(drawable);
   }
}
```

`R.layout.deletable_image`is a normal xml-layout with `<merge>` as root element (since the DeletableImageView already is a LinearLayout. Within the merge-Tag you have the ImageView and the Button.

```
<merge xmlns="...">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" .../>

  <Button android:id="@+id/delete_button" .../>

</merge>
```

In your code you don't add an ImageView, but your custom component and set the Listener as callback, so you can remove the custom component again.

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);


final DeletableImageView div = new DeletableImageView(this);

div.setImage(...); // add this method to DeletableImageView
div.setListener(this);

// either implement these in your custom component or directly set it in the <ImageView> in R.layout.deletable_image
div.setScaleType(...); 
div.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);


rl.addView(div);
```

The last step is to implement `deleteMe(DeletableImageView me)`. You have to hold a reference to your RelativeLayout and it should work by just calling `rl.removeView(me);`

Comment: Hi, actually users select as many emoji to set on their image for mask editing if they don't need emoji they can remove and emoji also can be moveable by touching on it so remove button with each emoji also should be moveable where it goes. Can I use this code for this purpose? I think I need to add wrapper like relative layout both for emoji and remove button and layout should be moveable as a result both will be moved.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but of course you can also `DeletableImageView extends RelativeLayout`to gain all properties of an RelativeLayout. Using DragAndDrop with View is a different story. For DragAndDrop google for "ViewDragHelper"

Comment: Hi, can you show me the example of  R.layout.deletable_image, how it should look like the layout?

Comment: I am getting error from this code: public setListener(DeletableImageListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    } saying there is no default constructor in widget.linerlayout

Comment: and also div.setImage(...) doesn't work, I think method has not be declared?

Comment: I added some code. Please don't just copy and paste this. Try to understand what's going on, so you learn what you can do with custom components. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html